# How to compute the difference between two time points (e.g., 11:30 am and 01:20 pm => 110 min)?

Tags: calculations, datetime

Is there a simple way to compute the difference between two times (same day), so 11:30 am and 01:20 pm should lead to 110 min (or 1h 50min), for example? I saw the `datenumber` package but it only seems to compute day differences (so works on a larger scale). [I didn't include a minimal example as I don't have any elegant way how to start the problem except for (ugly?) string 'divide-and-conquer' approaches]

Okay, I just also discovered `datetime` which looks more promising. Nevertheless, I don't see how one can compute differences of time points with this package (or `calc`?)

**Update**
After David's answer, I expanded the MWE to my original example and realized the following `Runaway argument`-problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mystart}{11:30 am}
\newcommand*{\myend}{01:20 pm}

% duration
\def\duration#1#2{%
  \the\numexpr(\xduration#2\relax)-(\xduration#1\relax)\relax\ minutes}

\def\xduration#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{%
(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720 \fi
}

% environment
\newenvironment{tbl}[3]{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    #1 & \duration{#2}{#3}\\
  \end{tabular}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbl}{Duration}{\mystart}{\myend}% Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \xduration.
%\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30 am}{01:20 pm}% works
\end{tbl}
\end{document}
```

How can this be avoided? [another pair of `{}` did not help]

Comment: Do you want the difference result as "110 minutes" or "1 hr 50 minutes"?

Comment: Convert the hour to minutes: `(hour if pm + 12 fi)*60 + minutes`; do the difference; convert back to hour and minutes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, both are okay, whatever is more convenient.

Comment: To fix your problem, replace `\xduration` with `\expandafter\xduration` in the definition of `\duration`.  (twice)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1#2{%
  \the\numexpr(\xfoo#2\relax)-(\xfoo#1\relax)\relax\ minutes}

\def\xfoo#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{%
%(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720 \fi
(#1)*60+#2\if p#3\ifnum#1=12 \else+720\fi\fi
}



\begin{document}

\foo{11:30 am}{01:20 pm}

\end{document}
```

If you want to expand the arguments before parsing, as in the edited MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mystart}{11:30 am}
\newcommand*{\myend}{01:20 pm}

% duration
\def\duration#1#2{%
  {\def\,{ }%
  \edef\tmp{%
   \noexpand\theminutes{%
   \noexpand\the
   \noexpand\numexpr
   (\noexpand\xduration#2\relax)-%
   (\noexpand\xduration#1\relax)\relax}}\tmp}}

\def\xduration#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{%
%(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720\fi
 (#1)*60+#2\if p#3\ifnum#1=12 \else+720\fi\fi
}

\def\theminutes#1{%
#1\ minute\ifnum#1=1 \else s\fi}

% environment
\newenvironment{tbl}[3]{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    #1 & \duration{#2}{#3}\\
  \end{tabular}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30 am}{01:20 pm}% works
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}{Duration}{\mystart}{\myend}% Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \xduration.
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30\,am}{01:20\,pm}% works
\end{tbl}



\begin{tbl}{Duration}{12:30 pm}{03:00 pm} % works
\end{tbl}


\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30\,am}{11:31\,am}
\end{tbl}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I realized a strange error when I use the "duration" command inside a table/environment. I updated the post. Do you see how to avoid this error?

Comment: @MariusHofert nothing to do with tabular, I parse looking for `:` to split up the time and you hid that in a macro, if you need to expand macros before parsing for minutes it needs another line...

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, David. I just had to put a `%` after `\edef\tmp{` to avoid a small horizontal space to be inserted. Works very well, thanks again.

Comment: Is it difficult to allow the input to have a half-space between the number and the unit, so `11:30\,am`?

Comment: Hi David, I then used `(#1)*60+#2#3\if p#5+720` inside the definition but I end up with `-610 min`. Do you know why?

Comment: The problem seems to be that the `p` is not matched and thus the `720` not added.

Comment: A solution could be to omit the time unit and simply test whether the start date is "larger" than the end date. If so, add 720. But I haven't figured out yet how to test ">="

Comment: sorry #4 cant be a space, I'll fix @MariusHofert

Comment: @MariusHofert updated answer

Comment: okay, works great in my actual example. Thanks a lot for helping, David.

Comment: Hi David, I just realized that `\begin{tbl}{Duration}{12:30 pm}{03:00 pm}` gives -570 minutes instead of 150. Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: @MariusHofert updated

Comment: Is it possible to use some sort of `\if` argument to get `minute` if it's `1` and `minutes` if it's anything else?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg updated

Comment: @MariusHofert updated again for Svend...

Comment: Nice! Can the macro be expanded to also deal with time differences between differnate dates. (For example compute the number of minutes from November 15th, 17:20 pm, to November 18th, 09:00 am.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg tex is turing complete so clearly the answer is yes but as written it doesn't even roll over midnight (as OP didn't need that) it wouldn't be hard, just tiresome.

Comment: Okay. I'll start a new question asking for this. `:)`

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on David's excellent answer, to give the alternative output, as

`xx hour(s) xx minute(s)`.

REEDITED to use singular "minute" and "hour" if there is only 1 of them.  Also, applied modulo fix when time was 12:xx (had to subtract 720 to treat 12 hour like 00 hour)

Here is the MWE (EDITED to expand the arguments, allowing them to be passed in macro form):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1#2{\edef\tmp{\numfoo{#1}{#2}}\tmp\ minute%
  \ifnum\tmp=1\relax\else s\fi}

\def\xfoo#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720\fi\ifnum#1=12-720\fi}

\def\numfoo#1#2{%
  \the\numexpr(\expandafter\xfoo#2\relax)-(\expandafter\xfoo#1\relax)\relax}

\def\barr#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr((\numfoo{#1}{#2})-(30))/60\relax}%
  \tmp\ hour\ifnum\tmp=1\relax\else s\fi\ %
  \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr(\numfoo{#1}{#2})-((\numfoo{#1}{#2})-(30))/60*60}%
  \tmp\ minute\ifnum\tmp=1\relax\else s\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\foo{11:30 am}{01:20 pm} = \barr{11:30 am}{01:20 pm}

\foo{11:30 am}{12:31 pm} = \barr{11:30 am}{12:31 pm}

\foo{12:30 am}{12:31 pm} = \barr{12:30 am}{12:31 pm}

\foo{11:59 am}{12:00 pm} = \barr{11:59 am}{12:00 pm}

\def\starttime{11:30 am}
\def\endtime{03:20 pm}

\foo{\starttime}{\endtime} = \barr{\starttime}{\endtime}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use some sort of `\if` argument to get `hour` if it's `1` and `hours` if it's anything else? (The same with `minute`/`minutes`.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Done, and fixed bug when time involved "12:xx"