# Compute the difference between two time points on different dates

Tags: programming, calculations, datetime

This is a follow-up question to [How to compute the difference between two time points (e.g., 11:30 am and 01:20 pm => 110 min)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203099/how-to-compute-the-difference-between-two-time-points-e-g-1130-am-and-0120).

Consider the code from David's excellent answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203103/15874):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mystart}{11:30 am}
\newcommand*{\myend}{01:20 pm}

% duration
\def\duration#1#2{%
  {\def\,{ }%
  \edef\tmp{%
   \noexpand\theminutes{%
   \noexpand\the
   \noexpand\numexpr
   (\noexpand\xduration#2\relax)-%
   (\noexpand\xduration#1\relax)\relax}}\tmp}}

\def\xduration#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{%
%(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720\fi
 (#1)*60+#2\if p#3\ifnum#1=12 \else+720\fi\fi
}

\def\theminutes#1{%
#1\ minute\ifnum#1=1 \else s\fi}

% environment
\newenvironment{tbl}[3]{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    #1 & \duration{#2}{#3}\\
  \end{tabular}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30 am}{01:20 pm}% works
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}{Duration}{\mystart}{\myend}% Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \xduration.
\end{tbl}

\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30\,am}{01:20\,pm}% works
\end{tbl}



\begin{tbl}{Duration}{12:30 pm}{03:00 pm} % works
\end{tbl}


\begin{tbl}{Duration}{11:30\,am}{11:31\,am}
\end{tbl}


\end{document}
```

Can the macro be expanded to also deal with time differences between differnate dates? (For example compute the number of minutes from November 15th, 17:20 pm, to November 18th, 09:00 am.)

**Update**

Following the nice [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212395/15874) of Steven B. Segletes, I would like to omit `<a> day(s)`, `<b> hour(s)`, and/or `<c> minute(s)` if the value(s) is/are zero.

Example 1: I would like `\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{10}{12}{01:20 pm}` to produce `1 hour and 50 minutes`.

Example 2: I would like `\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{10}{14}{08:50 am}` to produce `1 day, 21 hours and 20 minutes`. [I can implement the additional `,` and `and` myself, I assume.]

**Update 2**

I forgot two more thing:

- Can I get the output as `<a> days, <b> hours and <c> minutes = <d> minutes`, i.e., also get the output in minutes?
- Is it possible to input the time of the day as `<p>:<q>` where `<p>` is an integer between 0 and 24 and `<q>` is an integer between 0 and 59, instead of `<p>:<q> am`/`<p>:<q> pm`?

(I'll accept your answer as soon as the last thing is added.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `datenumber` package to do day arithmetic, and using my prior answer from the OP's cited question as the basis for my hr:mm arithmetic.  The `datenumber` package allows the conversion of a date into a counter number (relative to a reference date).

Syntax is:

`\timediff{year1}{month1}{day1}{h1:m1 am/pm}{year2}{month2}{day2}{h2:m2 am/pm}`

EDITED to provide `[m]` optional argument allowing output solely in minutes.  Also provide `\ampm[T/F]` to set the hours minutes as `{1:31 pm}` (T) or as `{13:31}` (F).

I should point out there is no error checking for the valid range of inputs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\gdef\mornaft{}

\def\xfoo#1:#2 #3m#4\relax{(#1)*60+#2\if p#3+720\fi\ifnum#1=12-720\fi}

\newcommand\ampm[1][T]{%
\if T#1%
 \def\numfoo##1##2{%
  \the\numexpr(\expandafter\xfoo##2\mornaft\relax)-%
    (\expandafter\xfoo##1\mornaft\relax)\relax}%
\else%
 \def\numfoo##1##2{%
  \the\numexpr(\expandafter\xfoo##2 am\relax)-%
    (\expandafter\xfoo##1 am\relax)\relax}%
\fi
}
\ampm

\def\barr#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr((\numfoo{#1}{#2})-(30))/60\relax}%
  \ifnum\tmp<0\relax\addtocounter{mydays}{-1}%
    \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr\tmp+24\relax}\fi%
  \ifnum\themydays=0\relax\else
    \themydays\ day\ifnum\themydays=1\else s\fi,\ \fi%
  \tmp\ hour\ifnum\tmp=1\relax\else s\fi\ and\ %
  \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr(\numfoo{#1}{#2})-((\numfoo{#1}{#2})-(30))/60*60}%
  \tmp\ minute\ifnum\tmp=1\relax\else s\fi%
}

\def\barm#1#2{%
  \edef\tmp{\the\numexpr(\value{mydays})*60*24+\numfoo{#1}{#2}}%
  \tmp\ minute\ifnum\tmp=1\else s\fi%
}

\newcounter{mystartdate}
\newcounter{mydays}

\newcommand\timediff[9][d]{%
  \setdatenumber{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \setcounter{mystartdate}{\value{datenumber}}%
  \setdatenumber{#6}{#7}{#8}%
  \setcounter{mydays}{\numexpr\value{datenumber}-\value{mystartdate}}%
  \if#1m\barm{#5}{#9}\else\barr{#5}{#9}\fi%
}

\begin{document}
\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{10}{12}{01:20 pm}

\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{10}{14}{08:50 am}

\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{11}{14}{07:00 am}

\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{11}{14}{12:31 pm}=
\timediff[m]{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{11}{14}{12:31 pm}

\timediff[m]{2014}{10}{12}{11:30 am}{2014}{10}{12}{11:31 am}

\ampm[F]
\timediff{2014}{10}{12}{11:30}{2014}{10}{12}{23:31}

\timediff[m]{2014}{10}{12}{11:30}{2014}{10}{12}{23:31}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice! I have a few more requests, which I'll add to my question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg  Please see revision.

Comment: I forgot two more things (sorry); I've updated my question again.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Please see re-revision.

Answer (score 7):

You could spend an hour or two writing this in TeX, or just use `--shell-escape` and

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\edef\pc{\csname @percentchar\endcsname}
\def\foo#1#2{%
time between #1 and #2 is
\input{"|echo '(' ` date  --date '#1' +\pc s`  - `date  --date '#2' +\pc s` ')/60' | bc"}%
minutes}

\foo{9am November 19 2014}{5pm November 15 2014}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to get `From <time, date, year> to <time, date, year> there are <n> minutes` [with commas between `time`, `date`, and `year`] and a space between, say, `5` and `pm`? (Btw., if you have an hour or two and don't know what to do with your time, you shall be more than welcome to write it in TeX.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg date is very flexible in what it accepts `now` for example:-) but exactly what it accepts depends on the version you have, the locale and other things, try `date --help` on the commandline. otherwise you can add `sed` to the pipe to remove commas and reorder fields

Comment: I'll try and fiddle with it; thanks. Just out of curiosity: Do yo think that you'll have time and energy to write it using TeX? `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg after I've done longtable v5, that's running at a rate of about 1 release every 10 years...

Comment: Okay. I just assumed that with your TeX skills it wouldn't take a very long time. `:)`

Comment: Btw. is there a time schedule for the release of [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) v5?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg my current plan is to release it before v6

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. `:)`