# A \def syntax problem

Tags: calculations

I want to compute a time difference.

For example:

- 22:44 - 22:50 -> 00:06
- 23:00 - 00:10 -> 01:10

In the second case, the time is implicitly about the following day.

My idea is:

1. Convert the times into their equivalent in total minutes (h*60+m).
2. Compute the difference.
3. Convert the difference back in the format `hh:mm`.

For the moment, I am stuck with a syntax error:

> Missing number, treated as zero. Missing ) inserted for expression.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\nok#1:#2\relax#3:#4\relax{%
    \def\tStart{\the\numexpr(#1*60+#2)}%
    \def\tEnd{\the\numexpr(#3*60+#4)}%
    \tEnd\ifnum\tEnd<\tStart+1440\fi%
}

\begin{document}

\the\numexpr(\nok22:44\relax22:50\relax)

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212364/compute-the-difference-between-two-time-points-on-different-dates or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203099/how-to-compute-the-difference-between-two-time-points-e-g-1130-am-and-0120

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approach without packages.

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
% Will be expandable, expands in two steps
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
% get arguments and evaluate time difference in minutes
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
% correct modulo 24*60 if difference turns out negative
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
% do Euclidean division by 60. Curse \numexpr rounding in passing.
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
% Get the remainder too, prepare for zero padding
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
% Output final result 
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\timedelta{22:40}{22:50}

\timedelta{23:00}{00:10}

\timedelta{08:24}{19:32}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In practice, one may want to use the `\timedelta` with arguments being themselves macros. But the above code does not expand the arguments. This led to follow-up question [Probably just another gdef-expansion problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400356/probably-just-another-gdef-expansion-problem).

I provided an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400360/4686) there which completes the above code with generated variants which expand their arguments.

Let me here simply extend the above code so that `\timedelta` automatically expands its two arguments. This expansion will be a so-called "full (first token) expansion", and in particular `\timedelta` can then be used as argument to itself, so that one can compute delta's of delta's etc... à la Newton iterated differences. Just in case you are idle for a while.

```
\documentclass{article}    

\makeatletter
% Will be expandable, expands in two steps

% Expands its arguments!

\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]%
  {\romannumeral0\expandafter\timedelta@h\expandafter
     {\romannumeral-`0#2}{#1}}%
\def\timedelta@h #1#2{\expandafter\timedelta@i\romannumeral-`0#2:#1:}

% get arguments and evaluate time difference in minutes
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
% correct modulo 24*60 if difference turns out negative
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
% do Euclidean division by 60. Curse \numexpr rounding in passing.
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
% Get the remainder too, prepare for zero padding
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
% Output final result 
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\timedelta{22:40}{22:50}

\timedelta{23:00}{00:10}

\timedelta{08:24}{19:32}

\newcommand\timeStart{00:02}
\newcommand\timeEnd{00:01}

\timedelta{\timeStart}{\timeEnd}

\timedelta{\timeEnd}{\timeStart}

\timedelta{\timedelta{10:00}{14:23}}{\timedelta{10:00}{14:22}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: All the response are excellent answers. Thx to everybody.

Answer (score 11):

`\numexpr` expressions have to *expand* to the numeric syntax so you can not have unexpandable assignments from `\def`

I think this is the calculation you intended

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\nok#1:#2\relax#3:#4\relax{%
\numexpr
 \numexpr(#3)*60+#4\relax
 \ifnum\numexpr(#1)*60+#2\relax<\numexpr(#1)*60+#2\relax+1440\fi
\relax
 }

\begin{document}

\the\numexpr(\nok22:44\relax22:50\relax)\relax

\end{document}
```

Comment: @jfbu I'll add a top level `\relax` :-)

Comment: +1........... then I can still point out that `\the\nok22:44\relax22:50\relax` works fine ;-)

Comment: @jfbu true, but only if you look inside the definition and see that you can prefix `\nok` with `\the`

Comment: any definition starting with `\def` deserves a peek inside!

Comment: I think we got busy discussing `\relax` but missed that you don't compute a difference here... (you did get the ticks) and now we have **3** additional answers, so I will add another one ;-)

Comment: This is the only answer which explains the error from the question...

Comment: @jfbu the _question_ is not about date calculation but why there was an error in the OPs code, this answer uses the same calculation as the OP but repeating that subterms rather than making a definition so it works by expansion.

Comment: I knew there must have been some reason why I upvoted: you are indeed the only one actually answering the question! ;-). Notice that I waited for all our comrades rolling out their computations for following suit... not my fault here...

Answer (score 8):

You can also use Lua, if you're willing to compile with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{dofile('timediff.lua')}
\def\wait#1#2{\directlua{tex.print(timediff('#1', '#2'))}}

\begin{document}
The time from 22:44 to 22:50 is \wait{22:44}{22:50}.

The time from 23:00 to 00:10 is \wait{23:00}{00:10}.
\end{document}
```

where `timediff.lua` is:

```lua
function hhms(s)
   -- Example: hhms('01:42') gives 102
   local _, _, hh, mm = string.find(s, "(%d*):(%d*)")
   return hh * 60 + mm
end

function timediff(time1, time2)
   -- Example: timediff('22:45', '01:15') gives '02:30'
   local t1 = hhms(time1)
   local t2 = hhms(time2)
   if t2 < t1 then t2 = t2 + 1440 end
   local d = t2 - t1
   local mm = d % 60
   local hh = (d - mm) / 60
   return string.format('%02d:%02d', hh, mm)
end
```

Later you may find Lua's [time and date](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) functions useful.

Answer (score 7):

The expected `expl3` answer providing the expected padding. This also support (single) macros in the input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\timedelta}{mm}
 {
  \joseph_timediff:ff { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \joseph_timediff:nn
 {
  \__joseph_timediff:ff
   { \__joseph_minutes:w #1 \q_stop }
   { \__joseph_minutes:w #2 \q_stop }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joseph_timediff:nn { ff }

\cs_new:Nn \__joseph_timediff:nn
 {
  \joseph_output:f
   {
    \int_eval:n { (#2) - (#1) \int_compare:nNnT { #2 } < { #1 } { + 1440 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__joseph_timediff:nn { ff }

\use:x
 {
  \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__joseph_minutes:w ##1 \token_to_str:N : ##2 \exp_not:N \q_stop
 }
 {
  #1 * 60 + #2
 }

\cs_new:Nn \joseph_output:n
 {
  \int_compare:nNnT { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 60 } } < { 10 } { 0 }
  \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 60 }
  :
  \int_compare:nNnT { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 60 } } < { 10 } { 0 }
  \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 60 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joseph_output:n { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\routeStart{01:27}
\newcommand\routeStop{01:27}

\begin{document}

\timedelta{22:40}{22:50}

\timedelta{23:00}{00:10}

\timedelta{08:24}{19:32}

\timedelta{\routeStart}{01:27}

\timedelta{16:03}{\routeStop}

\timedelta{\routeStart}{\routeStop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following assumes that times are of the form `HH:MM`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\makeatletter

\def\TheHour#1:#2@END{#1}
\def\TheMinute#1:#2@END{#2}

\newcommand{\timediff}[2]{%
  \two@digits{% HOUR
    \fpeval{(\TheHour#2@END)-(\TheHour#1@END)% Hour difference
            +(\ifnum\TheHour#2@END<\TheHour#1@END 24\else 0\fi)% Correction for time spanning midnight
            -(\ifnum\TheMinute#2@END<\TheMinute#1@END 1\else 0\fi)}% Minute correction
  }%
  {:}%
  \two@digits{% MINUTE
    \fpeval{(\TheMinute#2@END)-(\TheMinute#1@END)% Minute difference
            +(\ifnum\TheMinute#2@END<\TheMinute#1@END 60\else 0\fi)}% Minute correction
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$22{:}44 - 22{:}50 = \timediff{22:44}{22:50}$

$23{:}00 - 00{:}10 = \timediff{23:00}{00:10}$

$00{:}00 - 23{:}59 = \timediff{00:00}{23:59}$

$22{:}44 - 00{:}43 = \timediff{22:44}{00:43}$

$12{:}34 - 12{:}34 = \timediff{12:34}{12:34}$

\end{document}
```