# Probably a gdef-expansion problem, but how to solve?

Tags: calculations, arguments

Trying to integrate the answer of this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398023/a-def-syntax-problem) it into my real code,
I face the error

> Argument of \timedelta@i has an extra }

when calling the proposed method.
Upto now, I've not been able to fix it.
Can you help? Thx.

My current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% Routes Details
\newcommand{\routeInitial}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{startTime}
    & #1 & #2\\
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeStep}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{toTime}
    \timedelta{\routeFrom}{#3}\relax & #1 & #2\\%
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeFinal}[2]{%{icon}{Description}
    & #1 & #2\\%
}

% Duration
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\timedelta{16:03}{17:46}\\% This is working !

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \routeInitial{\faicon{home}}{}{16:03}%
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{17:46}% This is not working ! Argument of \timedelta@i has an extra }
    \routeStep{\faicon{beer}}{}{17:58}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{18:23}
    \routeStep{\faicon{cutlery}}{Royal Wok}{20:20}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{22:44}
    \routeStep{\faicon{female}}{}{22:50}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{01:27}
    \routeFinal{\faicon{hotel}}{Seligweiler}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have updated my [original answer to your original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398102/4686) to makethe `\timedelta` automatically expand its two arguments. I should have done that initially, this would have avoided you quite a few troubles, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't verify this completely, because FontAwesome isn't running on my machine, but you have to expand `\routeFrom` in the argument of `\timedelta` for `\routeStep`. Otherwise the structure of the data you give to `\timedelta@i` doesn't match your pattern. The following should work (and does if I remove the `fontawesome` related commands):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% Routes Details
\newcommand{\routeInitial}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{startTime}
    & #1 & #2\\
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeStep}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{toTime}
    \expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{\routeFrom}{#3}\relax & #1 & #2\\%
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeFinal}[2]{%{icon}{Description}
    & #1 & #2\\%
}

% Duration
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\timedelta{16:03}{17:46}\\% This is working !

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \routeInitial{\faicon{home}}{}{16:03}%
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{17:46}% This is not working ! Argument of \timedelta@i has an extra }
    \routeStep{\faicon{beer}}{}{17:58}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{18:23}
    \routeStep{\faicon{cutlery}}{Royal Wok}{20:20}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{22:44}
    \routeStep{\faicon{female}}{}{22:50}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{01:27}
    \routeFinal{\faicon{hotel}}{Seligweiler}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 and let's keep quiet else the LaTeX3 guys will comme haunt us and explain how simply they could have changed their macro to expand its arguments, simply by some "generate variant" xparse command...

Comment: @jfbu I could have done that in `expl3`, but I think the OP wanted to know where the error was, and not see 5 different approaches which wouldn't have this error :)

Comment: What do I have to do to make it work with a gdef as 2nd argument?
Let's say I have: \gdef\routeStop{01:27}

But when I call the method: 
\expandafter\timedelta{16:03}\expandafter{\routeStop}
I get the exception: Paragraph ended before \timedelta@i was complete.

Comment: In general `\gdef` isn't expandable, so I'd guess that's the problem here, but I don't understand what you exactly called from your comment...

Comment: I made a new post with a complete code sample here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400356/probably-just-another-gdef-expansion-problem

Answer (score 0):

With the code I proposed in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398059/4427)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\timedelta}{mm}
 {
  \joseph_timediff:ff { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \joseph_timediff:nn
 {
  \__joseph_timediff:ff
   { \__joseph_minutes:w #1 \q_stop }
   { \__joseph_minutes:w #2 \q_stop }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joseph_timediff:nn { ff }

\cs_new:Nn \__joseph_timediff:nn
 {
  \joseph_output:f
   {
    \int_eval:n { (#2) - (#1) \int_compare:nNnT { #2 } < { #1 } { + 1440 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__joseph_timediff:nn { ff }

\use:x
 {
  \cs_new:Npn \exp_not:N \__joseph_minutes:w ##1 \token_to_str:N : ##2 \exp_not:N \q_stop
 }
 {
  #1 * 60 + #2
 }

\cs_new:Nn \joseph_output:n
 {
  \int_compare:nNnT { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 60 } } < { 10 } { 0 }
  \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 60 }
  :
  \int_compare:nNnT { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 60 } } < { 10 } { 0 }
  \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 60 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joseph_output:n { f }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Routes Details
\newcommand{\routeInitial}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{startTime}
    & #1 & #2\\
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeStep}[3]{%{icon}{Description}{toTime}
    \timedelta{\routeFrom}{#3} & #1 & #2\\%
    \multirow{1}{*}[1.5ex]{#3}%
    \gdef\routeFrom{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\routeFinal}[2]{%{icon}{Description}
    & #1 & #2\\%
}


\begin{document}

Test of \verb|\timedelta|: \timedelta{22:40}{22:50}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lcl}
    \routeInitial{\faicon{home}}{}{16:03}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{17:46}
    \routeStep{\faicon{beer}}{}{17:58}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{18:23}
    \routeStep{\faicon{cutlery}}{Royal Wok}{20:20}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{22:44}
    \routeStep{\faicon{female}}{}{22:50}
    \routeStep{\faicon{car}}{}{01:27}
    \routeFinal{\faicon{hotel}}{Seligweiler}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]