# Probably just another gdef-expansion problem

Tags: calculations, arguments

In continuation of the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398438/probably-a-gdef-expansion-problem-but-how-to-solve), I try to make the following (simplified) code to work.

- \timedelta uses 2 arguments.
- Using a \gdef as the first argument is Ok.
- Using a \gdef as the second argument is Nok.

I cannot go away from the exception

> 21: Paragraph ended before \timedelta@i was complete. []

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\gdef\routeStart{01:27}
\expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{\routeStart}{01:27}% ok

\gdef\routeStop{01:27}
\expandafter\timedelta{16:03}\expandafter{\routeStop}% nok -> Paragraph ended before \timedelta@i was complete.

\end{document}
```

> My Edits after the first answers

How to "expand" the two arguments? Thx!

```
\timedelta{\routeStart}{\routeStop}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\timedelta{` applies expandafter to a `{` but that is not an expandable token

Comment: Note that you don't use the `\gdef` as argument, but a macro (here `\routeStart` or `\routeStop`).

Comment: sorry for not having made the [initial `\timedelta`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398102/4686) expand automatically its two arguments. I have now added this to this initial answer of your [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398023/a-def-syntax-problem). As per the question here, my answer defines `\timedeltaOO` and `\timedeltaXX` which both would work with `{\routeStart}{\routeStop}` arguments. But simpler to use the enhanced `\timedelta` [now there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398102/4686)

Comment: The second version perfectly fits my needs. Thks for the "ready to use" solution. Now, I have to study it ...

Answer (score 2):

This could help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\newcommand\timeatled[2]{\timedelta{#2}{#1}}

\newcommand\timedeltaON[2]{\expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\timedeltaNO[2]{\expandafter\timeatled\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\newcommand\timedeltaOO[2]{\expandafter\timedeltaNO\expandafter{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand\timedeltaXN[2]
    {\expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\timedeltaNX[2]
    {\expandafter\timeatled\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#2}{#1}}
\newcommand\timedeltaXX[2]
    {\expandafter\timedeltaNX\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}


\gdef\routeStart{01:27}
\timedeltaON{\routeStart}{01:27}% ok

\timedeltaOO{\routeStart}{01:27}% ok

\timedeltaXX{\routeStart}{01:27}% ok

\gdef\routeStop{01:27}

\timedeltaNO{16:03}{\routeStop}% ok

\timedeltaOO{16:03}{\routeStop}% ok

\timedeltaXX{16:03}{\routeStop}% ok

\end{document}
```

[image]

LaTeX3 has a "generate variant" all purpose facility which solves these problems once and for all...

Notice that `\timedeltaXX` can be nested with itself (i.e. serve as either first or second argument of itself).

Comment: original `\timedelta` should have expanded its arguments but I was too lazy... (i.e. what is called `\timedeltaXX` here should have been the original `\timedelta`).

Comment: `O` stands for "open = expand once" and `N` for "nothing special, take argument as is", and `X` for "force expansion of first token until non further expandable" (this is in itself expandable operation, contrarily to putting the argument in an `\edef`, which would break expandability of `\timedelta` macro)

Comment: +1 for the `\romannumeral` trick (never would have thought of it, to be honest)

Comment: @Skillmon it is part of each TeXpandabler's bag of tricks and passes from generation to generation...

Answer (score 1):

You misuse `\expandafter`. A way how you could expand the second argument of the macro would be, to define a second macro, which contains the macro and its first argument and then use `\expandafter`s to expand an argument prior to execute that second macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\timedelta}[2]{\romannumeral0\timedelta@i#1:#2:}%
\def\timedelta@i #1:#2:#3:#4:%
   {\expandafter\timedelta@ii\the\numexpr#3*60+#4-#1*60-#2.}%
\def\timedelta@ii#1{\expandafter\timedelta@iii\the\numexpr
                    \if-#11440\fi #1}%
\def\timedelta@iii#1.{\expandafter\timedelta@iv\the\numexpr
                    (#1 + 30)/60 -1.#1.}%
\def\timedelta@iv #1.#2.{\expandafter\timedelta@v\the\numexpr
                    100+#2-60*#1\expandafter.\the\numexpr100+#1.}
\def\timedelta@v 1#1.1#2.{ #2:#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\gdef\routeStart{01:27}
\expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{\routeStart}{01:27}% ok

\gdef\routeStop{01:27}
\def\tempmacro{\timedelta{16:03}}%
\expandafter\tempmacro\expandafter{\routeStop}%
%\expandafter\timedelta{16:03}\expandafter{\routeStop}% nok -> Paragraph ended before \timedelta@i was complete.

\end{document}
```

What `\expandafter` does is (unprecisely described) it expands the second token prior to the first one (if it's expandable). In your example, every character of the first argument is a token, the correct way would be therefore jumping over each of those characters using an `\expandafter`, so the correct way to use `\expandafter` in that case would be:

```
\expandafter\timedelta\expandafter{\expandafter1\expandafter6\expandafter:\expandafter0\expandafter3\expandafter}\expandafter{\routeStop}%
```

Which is really cumbersome...